# ARM ASM + array

Tags: assembly, arm

I need help to write ARM assembly language routines to initialize an array X of size N with a constant value V, using two different approaches: indices, pointers

I have no idea how to do this in asm.

Thanks
jj

Comment: Your "question" sounds too much like "do my work for me". SO works when people try something, get stuck and ask for help. Show some more effort and details and you will receive plenty of help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you do this in a different language (using either of those approaches)? Do you know the basics of assembly syntax (registers, commands, etc)?

Comment: I'm taking ARM class. I understand the loop part of the code. I'm not sure about how to increase like in c  int x [ ] for indice and int *x for pointers.

__asm void foo (uint32 *array, uint32 size, uint32 value)

Loop
    LDR R3, [R0]              
    ADD R1, R1, R3          
    ADD R0, R0, #+4        
    SUBS R2, R2, #0x1    
    BNE Loop                  
    STR R1, Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest (not fastest) way to implement your function in ARM assembly language:

```
 .global foo
@
@ call from C as void foo(uint32 *array, uint32 size, uint32 value);
@
@ standard calling convention:
@ Values passed in register R0=*array, R1=size, R2=value
@
foo:
  str r2,[r0],#4   @ Store the value and increment the pointer
  subs r1,r1,#1    @ decrement the count
  bne foo          @ branch until the count is 0
  bx lr            @ return to caller
```

Comment: To supplement this answer, In **ARM** any register can be a value or a pointer.  Just use `ldr/str [rX]` to make it a pointer.  An *index* would be the addressing mode `[Rbase, Ridx]`.  See [Summary of addressing modes](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/301/ARM-addressing/lecture.html) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) for the concept you need to grok; Dwelch has similar info in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just like in C for example you can have a pointer that you basically destroy by changing it

```
*ptr; 
...
ptr++;
```

And you can use an array with an offset

```
data[x]; 
...
x++;
```

Arm provides a couple of addressing modes for that one is a register with an immediate offset (which you can have zero as an offset)

```
ldr r0,[r1]
```

The offset of zero is implied

```
ldr r0,[r1,#0]
```

You dont have to type it if you dont want to the assembler will encode it that way though.

Then you modify r1 (in this case) to move through memory (through the array).

The other addressing mode is a register offset

```
ldr r0,[r1,r2]
```

Where you can have one of the two registers be the base of the array and the other the index that moves through it.

Look these up in the arm docs and figure out how to use them properly to complete your homework.

Register indirect addressing for load and store is extremely common in instruction sets, not just ARM.  Having an immediate offset to it is as well.  Two register is also common, perhaps not as common though.  These tie directly in to the pointer and array programming models in higher level languages.